# Configuring the SessionFactory in SpringBoot + Spring data JPA + MySql project

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sessionfactory

I have been writing my first project with SpringBoot + Spring Data JPA. I use MySql as my database provider. I am sort of new to Spring Boot and Hibernate.

I followed the tutorial available at http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/ for my project.

Everything is clear up until the session factory. The mentioned tutorial does not use a session factory; instead it uses `CrudRepository` based transactions. But in my case, since I am still new to Hibernate, I use SessionFactory for db operations.

In my project, the DaoImpl class looks like follows.

```
@Repository
public class ReadDaoImpl implements ReadDao{

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    public static void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        TenderReadDaoImpl.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Read> getAllReads() {

        System.out.println("DEBUG: Inside ReadDaoImpl.getAllReads");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); // I think that the issue comes from here
        Transaction tx = null;
        ..............................
        ..............................
    }
}
```

My project starts running on the server without any issue. But when I access the relevant url for getAll() method, Eclipse console prints out a Null Pointer Exception referring to the following line.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

I think that I miss some configurations for `sessionFactory`. But I cannot figure out what it is.

Here is my `application.properties` file. It is in fact a copy of the same file from the above link.

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database 
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/readsdb?useSSL=false

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

In my project, there is no any configuration file. Do I need to add a one to create `sessionFactory` Bean? I came across something called `entityManagerFactory`. Do I need to configure the `sessionfactory` through that for this Spring Jpa based project? If so, How?

I am completely out of solutions at the moment. Guide me to get this thing done. It would be much helpful for me if the exhaustive way of doing this can be pointed out.

Thanks..!

Comment: Have you solved this one ? I am also facing the same one.

Comment: Unfortunately no. However, I was able to get things done using entityManager based db connection

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Have SessionFactory configured explicitly in your @Configuration class this way. Remove configuration from properties file. I use Oracle, you can replace mysql properties accordingly:

```
@Configuration
public class myConfiguration {
 //datasource bean
    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource  getDataSource() {        
        DataSourceBuilder b = DataSourceBuilder.create();
         b.url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
         b.driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         b.username("system");
         b.password("system");
        return b.build();
    }


    //sessionfactory bean
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("ORM.Model");

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();       
    }

    //Hibernate properties:
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {       
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect");        
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");     
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        return properties;
    }

    //transaction manager bean
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```